# Seperate Number from Text

Tags: regex, string, google-sheets, numbers, decimal

I'm working in google sheets and I need to separate
`876,87.689APPLES` into  876,87.689 and APPLES, in two different fields.

With the command

```
=value(regextract(field,"-*\d*\.?\d+")),
```

I get 876,87,689

It ignores the fact that its a decimal number.

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[0-9,\.]+"), REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[0-9,\. ]+", )}
```

[image]